# Adobe - Brackets : view existing variables and methods of a variable from IDE - Extension

Tags: adobe-brackets

Is there any extension, that can help us to view together all the variables and methods of an object from Adobe-Brackets IDE?

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this below extension.

https://github.com/Hirse/brackets-outline-list

Hope it helps,

Cheers.